# HTACCESS rewrite with get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a sub directory which has a bunch of .php files in it. I currently have this as my .HTACCESS to rewrite the urls cleanly.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /mailing_list

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This is fine because it turns http://www.example.com/mailing_list/home to look at http://www.example.com/mailing_list/home.php

What I also need to account for is a page using clean urls for the get variables. That page is called w.php and it passes `?i=(int)`

When I try to access http://www.example.com/mailing_list/w/1 I get a 505 server error. What do I need to add to my htaccess to account for this? Is there a full proof way which will account for others I run in to. For example:

What if a page comes up called blogs and it passes the ID of the blog like this: http://www.example.com/mailing_list/blog/1

Will I have to add a new Rule for that page specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

by

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?i=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks! If I want to just target the directory /w would I remove ([^/]+)/ and replace with w/ ?